# Unity - Sorting a nested list

Tags: list, sorting, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a nested List in Unity. I have my:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class HistoryRecordList
{
    public int recordDate;
    public string record;
}
```

And my list here:

```
public class InputMachine : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public List<HistoryRecordList> historyRecords = new List<HistoryRecordList>();

    public void AddToHistory(int ID, string description)
    {
        HistoryRecordList list = new HistoryRecordList();
        list.recordDate = ID;
        list.record = description;

        historyRecords.Add(list);
    }
}
```

I like to sort the list "historyRecords" by recordDate;
I know, there is a list.Sort() function but I don't know how to apply it to a nested list. Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Comment: I'm positive the answer is Linq but I can never remember the syntax lol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: You would not need to sort each time you add, you would do binary sort insertion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780682/linq-way-to-insert-element-in-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

---

### `LINQ`

**Implement** (Ascending)

```cs
private static List<HistoryRecordList> SortRecordDate(IEnumerable<HistoryRecordList> list)
{
  return list.OrderBy(x => x.recordDate).ToList();
}
```

**How to use**

```cs
historyRecords = SortRecordDate(historyRecords);
```

---

### `List<>.Sort(Comparison<T>)`

**Implement** (Ascending)

```cs
private static void SortRecordDate(List<HistoryRecordList> list)
{
  list.Sort((x, y) => x.recordDate.CompareTo(y.recordDate));
}
```

**Implement** (Descending)

```cs
private static void SortRecordDate(List<HistoryRecordList> list)
{
  list.Sort((x, y) => y.recordDate.CompareTo(x.recordDate));
}
```

**How to use**

```cs
SortRecordDate(historyRecords);
```

---

Hope your problem is solved :)